# Unable to unlock boot-loader and root Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4501

Tags: rooting, bootloader, android-one

I have Micromax Canvas A1 AQ4501 which comes under Android One. It’s upgraded to Android 6.0.1. I tried to unlock its boot-loader but it’s not successful.

I did
•   adb reboot bootloader
•   adb devices (it shows device.)
•   fastboot oem unlock (after this command its stuck on 'waiting for device')
•   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img (after this command its stuck on 'waiting for device')

I changed USB cable and plugged it in another port but no changes.

I tried to root it using Kingo Root from PC. After 15 to 16%, it says, failed. Please help me to fix this issue.

Regards
GNS

Comment: Pointer: If `adb devices` shows your device, `fastboot` cannot see it. [`fastboot`](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) only works when booted into [bootloader](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader/info) mode.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello GNS

How many time did you try to root your device ? You may need to try it more than ones, just like my old galaxy tablet.


And if that is not successfull, try using different one click root application.
Here are the list of some of this applications

- Vroot Software (ADB drivers needed)
- Kingo Root For Windows (ADB Drivers Needed)
- SRS Root (ADB Drivers Needed )
- Framaroot (APK)
- KingRoot (APK and PC)
- Unlock Root Software
- Root Master (APK)
- Z4Root (APK)
- Universal Androot (APK)

Or you may visit [This](http://www.3ptechies.com/9-best-software-apps-to-root-android-devices.html) site for more information.

Comment: Hi..thank you for replying. Except Kingo Root, most of applications are either in Chinese language or detected as threat by the antivirus. And I tried Kingo Root for Windows. And After 15 to 16%, it says, failed.